# How can I change the scatterplot character in the gnuplot dumb terminal?

Tags: gnuplot

In gnuplot's dumb terminal, I can plot multiple series of 2D data like so:

```
set terminal dumb 79 24
plot "series1.dat", "series2.dat"
```

Points in series 1 are represented as the 'A' character; points in series 2 as 'B', and so on:

[image]

I can set the point type as follows:

```
plot "series1.dat" pt 1
```

but all the point types are just A-Z modulo `pt` (that is, 1 = 'A', 26 = 'Z', 27 = 'A', etc.)

It would be easier to understand my plot if I could set one of these to, say, `*` or `.`. How can I set the point in each series to something of my choosing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In version 5.0, you can do this by specifying the character as the point type

```
plot "series1.dat" pt "*"
```

will use the * character as the point.

For example, with the data

```
1 2
5 8
3 9
```

we get

```
10 +-+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-+
   +             +             +             +             +             +
   |                    *                                                |
   |                                                                     |
 8 +-+                                *                                +-+
   |                                                                     |
   |                                                                     |
   |                                                                     |
 6 +-+                                                                 +-+
   |                                                                     |
   |                                                                     |
 4 +-+                                                                 +-+
   |                                                                     |
   |                                                                     |
   |                                                                     |
 2 +-+    *                                                            +-+
   |                                                                     |
   |                                                                     |
   +             +             +             +             +             +
 0 +-+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-+
   0             2             4             6             8             10
```

where the * character is used for the point.

This is documented under `help points` which says *...any single printable character may be given instead of a point type...*.

Comment: @bibi It works just fine as I wrote it.  Probably because the default for a data file is the points style.  Of course, it may not work with a different style set.

Comment: Huh ... I probably should have thought of that! Much obliged.

Answer (score 2):

You ask:

> It would be easier to understand my plot if I could set one of these to, say, * or .

I have `gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 6` (2013), and although @Matthew's `pt` solution does not work for me, if you merely want one of the two series to be a dot `.`, you actually can do:

```
plot "series1.dat", "series2.dat" with dots
```

### Example

series1.dat:

```
1   1
2   2
```

series2.dat:

```
4   6
5   7
7   5
8   5
```

start gnuplot, then

```
set term dumb 79, 24

plot "series1.dat", "series2.dat" with dots
```

result:

```
7 ++--------+---------+---------+----------.---------+---------+--------++
  +         +         +         +          +        "series1.dat"   A    +
  |                                                 "series2.dat"   .    |
6 ++                            .                                       ++
  |                                                                      |
  |                                                                      |
5 ++                                                           .        +.
  |                                                                      |
  |                                                                      |
4 ++                                                                    ++
  |                                                                      |
  |                                                                      |
  |                                                                      |
3 ++                                                                    ++
  |                                                                      |
  |                                                                      |
2 ++        A                                                           ++
  |                                                                      |
  +         +         +         +          +         +         +         +
1 A+--------+---------+---------+----------+---------+---------+--------++
  1         2         3         4          5         6         7         8
```

- The `series1.dat` remains the default `with lines` style
- however `series2.dat` is rendered with `dots` style which generates `.` for each point

Comment: I checked, and it seems my solution does require newer than 4.6.  I added a version disclaimer to my solution.  Your solution works for the dots, but it won't for other symbols like the OP asked.  That may not be possible in 4.6.

Comment: Awesome. I have the latest so will go with the solution above, but this is good to know.